# What prevents bad domain registry behavior?

Tags: domain-name-system

There are now thousands of top level domains available. They were auctioned off by ICANN and are run by independent entities. Some of them are based in countries that may not have strong protections against government tampering. Aside from this, registration prices seem to be set solely by the registry.

What prevents bad behavior such as tampering with record lookups or price gouging at renewal time? Can ICANN remedy abuses by registries? What protections are in place? Is there any information available about how much abuses have happened in the past?

Answer (score 1):

First, some precisions:

> They were auctioned off by ICANN

No, things did not happen exactly like that. Companies applied for TLD strings. For some TLDs they were more than one applicants. In those cases either everything went down to only 1 applicant after later phases (financial and technical assessments) or applicants decided between themselves and all but one withdrew its application, or indeed at the very end it went into some auctions. It could be in private, or through ICANN specific mechanism for auctions (where the winner basically gets most of the amount bid by others). For that specific case, see https://newgtlds.icann.org/en/applicants/auctions with links to all past auctions and their results (and amounts exchanged).

> Some of them are based in countries that may not have strong protections against government tampering

This is highly subjective, specially since you do not name anyone.
But gTLD registries are under contract with ICANN. Among the copious amount of their obligations, registries have to publish in their nameservers the information of domains registered with the authoritative nameservers for each domain, as set forth by the registrant through the registrar. Both registrar and registries have rules and SLA to follow about getting new orders from registrant and applying them.

I am not sure exactly about which tampering you think about but if it is to the tune of "the registry is publishing other nameservers for a given domain name", then that would go against ICANN contracts and hence ultimately the registry could lose the TLD (and ICANN has a specific program running with emergency back-end operators to be able to transition TLDs to them in very short time frame).

One may say that what you have in mind can be more of a problem in ccTLD land, because there the TLD is really at the end of the day under control of the government and ICANN will have almost no power for any kind of dispute in it.

> registration prices seem to be set solely by the registry.

This is not "seem", this is a fact for any new TLD in this "2012 batch" so almost all of them but not some historical ones, like .COM/.NET
Or not yet at least since for example .ORG was also an historical one with some price cap and it just transitioned, among ample outcry, to the 2012 model.

Registries have some fees to pay to ICANN, both as fixed amount and as an amount per domain year, depending on the TLD size.
Registries are free to change their prices, in both directions, and set some domains apart as premiums and apply different pricing rules to them.

Registries price changes happen in the past. Registrars will often announce it in some way (in theory registry prices are confidential), like offering specific promotions just before a price change. Registries are just mandated to notify their registrars of their price change some months in advance. And of course prices apply the same way for all registrars, besides some promotional discounts that can happen based on registrars activities.

> What prevents bad behavior such as tampering with record lookups or price gouging at renewal time? Can ICANN remedy abuses by registries? What protections are in place? Is there any information available about how much abuses have happened in the past?

Unfortunately you may need to define "abuse"  here a little more, and especially why specifically concentration on gTLD, why do you think they would be more ripe for abuse?

What is price gouging at renewal time for you at registries level? Like explained above registries (the 2012 ones) are free to change their prices, this is notified to registrars and in turn they change (or not) their prices. There is little else that can happen here.

As for tampering with record lookups, like I wrote above, that would be a breach of ICANN contract. You may think it would be hard to detect, which can be true if done on a small targeted scale. But otherwise registries are also required to escrow all their data at least daily so in theory someone (at ICANN) could review changes in the past... but for content in the DNS in fact anyone could do it since zonefiles are public and anyone can download them, again, at least once daily, and hence monitor domains and nameservers changes. A lot of companies do that online.

ICANN has certainly leverage on gTLDs but not on ccTLDs. I find it strange in your question that you list problems that can theoretically happen with any TLD, but then you concentrate only on the ones in contract with ICANN. Also gTLDs are certainly not uniformly installed in the world, so some governments theoretically have far more leverage on more of them than other governments. Remember also that ICANN is US-based, as well as the operator of the primary root-server (VeriSign), so this, again theoretically, gives more power to one specific government in the world, which is also a reason to often hear other countries like China, Brazil or Russia to want their own "Internet" and not depending on the US anymore.

Also, you seem to fear governments forcing registries to change records: but they do not need to! Typically, a government could wish to make a given domain kind of disappear from Internet because it contravenes some local laws, so at least it should not be visible from the country. For that, even if it is a very imperfect solution, they just need to ask the major ISPs in the country to blacklist the domain. This happens today in many countries, even democratic ones. It may become more a problem in the future with DNS over HTTPS and browsers using that instead of the OS configuration and hence possible the ISP recursive nameservers.

Answer (score 0):

Very little, and the answer depends on the registry.

Certainly "Increased prices" for renewal are common, although generally this can be mitigated against by a domain transfer process mandated by the registry.

Government tampering is possible,but unlikely on a wide scale.  The Registrar generally provides TLD nameservers, so the furthest they could go would be to provide a non-correct nameservers.  As most people don't use the TLD nameservers directly, and as nameserver records are typically heavily cached, a change to these records would likely not be highly targetted and would be quite visible.

I am not an expert on abuses, but even within established TLD's, abuses are ripe, and ICANN dont appear to care.  Very often registering a domain name results in a slew of phonecalls from people who should not have knowledge of the domain registration wanting to sell you stuff.  ICANN could easily track this down and stomp on registrars leaking this, but they choose to turn a blind eye.

I guess to some extent, "the market" will help regulate this - there is no requirement to use a vanity domain name, and if abuses become to egregious, people will stop registering the domain name in theory.

Comment: The wholesale price cannot be avoided by transferring. It is a base coat incurred at the registry (not registrar) level.

Comment: Even if many do not use the registry's nameservers directly, the information from any nameservers ultimately came from the registry's nameservers. So if the registry tampers and changes a second level domain to point to malicious ip, it would effectively be hijacking the domain from the proper owner and this would propogate through all nameservers. Yes, it would be visible, but unless the domain is a popular one, I can't see what would prevent untrustworthy registries from continuing that behavior.

Comment: Regarding "people who should not have knowledge", according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WHOIS), "Currently, the Internet Corporation for Assigned Names and Numbers (ICANN) broadly requires that the mailing address, phone number and e-mail address of those owning or administrating a domain name to be made publicly available through the "WHOIS" directories."  So I don't think this is about TLDs misbehaving, there is a policy debate as to whether registrations *should* be private or public.  (GDPR has thrown a spanner in the works there as well.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston I was referring to breaches of https://whois.icann.org/en/whois-marketing-restriction-policy-wmrp. ItIts OK if someone wants to contact me about something specific to my behaviour, but not for them to spam me for registering a domain.

Comment: @HarryJohnston With the arrival of the GDPR some temporary specifications where put in place for whois and now RDAP: no email should be available through these channels but only ways to contact the registrant, either through a proxy email or a webform.

Comment: @davidgo What you reference is a very specific amendment to a very specific case: by ICANN rules, all registrars are required to **sell** their whole content (what is exposed in whois) to anyone asking for it, if memory serves well for at most $10000 per year. This transaction is made through an agreement that basically forbids the third party acquiring all this data to use it for marketing purposes.